# Creating a callout with a custom view for ArcGIS Runtime for iOS

Tags: ios, arcgis

I'm trying to create a callout with a custom view for ArcGIS for iOS, but I can't quite figure out how. More specifically, I want to create one that looks like the sample displayed in their "Display a callout" Guide at https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/objective-c/guide/map-callout.htm.

There's a callout at the bottom of the section titled "Customizing a callout's appearance", but I'm unable to duplicate its look. To wit, the displayed sample has a black background with rounded corners. I'm able to provide a black-looking UIView for the content of the callout (this is actually trivial), but it's presented inside a white-bordered balloon-type frame that has square corners, I'm unable to figure out how to make the white border either disappear or be black, with softer corners.

Anyone know how to make this happen? I'm hoping that since they're displaying what looks like an actual image, that this is possible.

TIA,
Howard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callout in the guide is from iOS6 that default callout color is black with 0.8 alpha. but in iOS7, 7.1, 8 they'va changed the default to white. If you want to change the color you can change it by set the color property.

[AGSCallout Color Property](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_callout.html#ac12a2835b968f7cd3cbe5c82d3029ddd)

Comment: Good answer. I don't know how I missed that. The one thing I still can't do however is to use my own custom view and have parts of that custom view extend to the boundaries of the callout. There's always a 4- or 5-pixel boundary 'inset' surrounding my custom view. At least now tho I can make that inset whatever color I want. Thanks.